# Swift bad instruction error shopping list

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, button, exc-bad-instruction

I have a problem, Xcode gives me this error "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode==0*0)" while I'm trying to make my buttons delete indexes in my array, "shoppingList".
Please help me and tell me what i did wrong so i can improve later on.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ShoppingList
//
//  Created by Petr Chrastek on 29/03/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 ACS. All rights reserved.
//
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var labelText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label0: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
    var shoppingList = ["eggs", "milk", "cake", "sugar"]

    @IBAction func remove0(sender: UIButton) {
        shoppingList.removeAtIndex(0)
    }

    @IBAction func remove1(sender: UIButton) {
        shoppingList.removeAtIndex(1)
    }

    @IBAction func remove2(sender: UIButton) {
        shoppingList.removeAtIndex(2)
    }

    @IBAction func remove3(sender: UIButton) {
        shoppingList.removeAtIndex(3)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let str: String? = shoppingList[0]
        let str1: String? = shoppingList[1]
        let str2: String? = shoppingList[2]
        let str3: String? = shoppingList[3]
        let count = shoppingList.count
        labelText.text? = "you are missing \(count) items"
        if str != nil {
            label0.text? = "\(str)"
        } else {
            label0.text? = "empty"
        }
        if str1 != nil {
            label1.text? = "\(str1)"
        } else {
            label1.text? = "empty"
        }
        if str2 != nil {
            label2.text? = "\(str2)"
        } else {
            label2.text? = "empty"
        }
        if str3 != nil {
            label3.text? = "\(str3)"
        } else {
            label3.text? = "empty"
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you delete the first item from your list, `shoppingList` will only have 3 items in it, so accessing `shoppingList[3]` will crash (remember with 3 items only 0..<2 are valid.

The easiest way to resolve the problem is to use the following pattern so you're checking the count to make sure indices are valid before using them.

```
if shoppingList.count > 0 {
    label0.text = shoppingList[0]
} else {
    label0.text = "empty"
}

if shoppingList.count > 1 {
    label1.text = shopingList[1]
} else {
    label1.text = "empty"
}
```

I've made some additional changes as well, such as not pointless using string interpolation to turn a `String` into the same `String`, since `[String][n]` will always return a `String` (never a `String?`) there's no need to deal with the `Optionals`

You'll have similar problems (in fact, probably what you're running into now) when you try to:

```
shoppingList.removeAtIndex(3)
```

the second time, since 3 is no longer a valid index, instead, use:

```
if shoppingList.count > 3 {
    shoppingList.removeAtIndex(3)
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, `Array` index bounds are strictly checked, unlike `Dictionary` where typically a missing index will simply return `nil`